# Durandal Modals and navigation (i.e. back button)

Tags: durandal

This issue is easily seen in the durandal sample application:

1) Navigate to "Modal Dialogs" demo
2) Click the button to show the modal
3) Click the browser back button

When doing this, the page navigates to the previous screen while keeping the dialog open, which is almost never what you want.

Is there a best practice here for either closing dialogs or preventing navigation if one is open?

Answer (score 1):

You can tie into the canDeactivate callback.  Check if the modal is open and either prevent it or if they want to leave, close it

Comment: This is good advice, though with 40+ viewmodels whereby each can have several potential dialogs, it would be ton of repetative work to address the issue this way.

Comment: It is only feasible to have one dialog open at a time.  Have an observable flag on your shell or other module of isDialogOpen and increment it as a counter as they open and decrement when they close.

Comment: Actually we have several instances of dialog-within-dialog.  However I did try a similar approach using an array pushing dialogs as they opened and removing as they closed.  It worked reasonably well, though I found the answer I posted provided the same functionality with a bit more isolation.

Comment: Eh, all it takes is a "Are you sure you want leave?" within a wizard to hit this requirement :) `

Answer (score 1):

While I don't expect this answer to be immediately applicable to many out there, I wanted to throw it out there in case it helps someone.

We use typescript to create our viewmodels, and we have a base viewmodel to encapsulate common functionality (as well as expose the dataservice, pub/sub, etc).  In this viewmodel this approach seems to work well:

```
public ShowDialog(viewModel: any) {
    // create a subscription to the router so that we can forcibly close the dialog in the event of a routing call
    var subscription = router.on('router:route:activating');
    subscription.then(() => {
        // we will hit this block if the router is activating while this dialog is open
        var moduleId = viewModel.__moduleId__ || '[No Id]';
        system.log('Navigation detected while dialog is open - the dialog will now be forcibly closed. (' + moduleId + ')', viewModel);
        dialog.close(viewModel);
    });

    var promise = App.showDialog(viewModel);
    promise.then(() => {
        subscription.off(); // kill the router subscription since the dialog is closed at this point
    });

    return promise;
}
```

Consumers can use this function as a direct substitution to durandals' dialog to opt-in to the auto-close functionality.